# Sharing the `node_modules` folder between the container and the host

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

This is a pretty hot topic, but I've never actually found a solution.

As you probably know, when we have a volume in a container and we install the dependencies (with `npm i` or something) from a Dockerfile (with default perms), Npm will create a `node_modules` folder in the container with `root:root` access.

I'm facing two issues with this method (on a local/dev environment):

1. The `node_modules` folder only exists inside the container, but the host's IDE/LSPs needs this folder to work properly (module imports, type definitions, etc).
2. If the host wants to install/update a package (`npm i ...`, etc) he will have to restart and rebuild the container for the `node_modules` folder to be updated.

So I came up with another idea, what if I install the dependencies using `CMD` in a Dockerfile (or the `command` property of a service in a `docker-compose` file) and use a volume so the `node_modules` can be shared with the host. Unfortunately, this method introduces new issues. For instance, the `node_modules` has a `root:root` permissions access, so if your host's username is "named" otherwise and doesn't have the same `uid` & `gid` you will need to run root access commands update the `node_modules` (`sudo npm i ...`).

Here is my current config:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: 'app_DEV'
    build: .
    command: sh -c "yarn install && node ./server.js"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    tty: true
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.8.1-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

`server.js`:

```js
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App is listening on port 3000'));
```

Then you can try to run `docker-compose up` and do a `ls -la`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mint mint   215 août  23 16:39 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 mint mint    56 août  23 16:29 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x 52 root root  4096 août  23 16:31 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 mint mint    53 août  23 16:31 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 mint mint   160 août  23 16:29 server.js
```

As you can see every files/folders have `mint:mint` access except `node_modules` (`mint` is my host's user).

So to sum up my question: is there a better way to manage NodeJS dependencies with Docker containers?

Comment: You can use the [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction in your dockerfile in order to not run everything as root but run it as a specific user. Which, security wise is a better idea, instead of running everything as root.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε With an hard coded uid / gid ? If yes, will the image be reusable ? And do they need to be the same as my host for him to be able to modifie the `node_modules` folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few years have pasted since I originally wrote this question. I wanted to come back and share a different opinion, since my POV has changed a bit since then, and I now think the way I wanted to use containers is incorrect.

First of all, pretty much any file/folder created in a container shouldn't be altered outside this same container.
In the context of this post, any command altering the `node_modules` folder should be run from within the container. I understand it can be a bit cumbersome, but I think it's fine as long as you use docker-compose (e.g. `docker-compose exec app npm i`).
I think it fits better the way OCI containers are intended to be used.

On the OS compatibility side, since everything (dev environment related) should be done from inside the container, there shouldn't be any issue.
Note that I've seen organizations distributing dev images both with uninstalled and preinstalled dependencies. I think both ways are fine, it just really depends on whether you want a lightweight dev image or not.

Comment: While this usually works great, it can cause problems when host is a different architecture than the container and the project needs a native module (like esbuild). The IDE on the host may complain even if HMR etc. works inside the container. Any additional idea how to solve that without having to install node_modules on the host and in the container separately?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, I would not recommend this approach since you're host & container might not be able to share the same modules. For example, if someone else on your team uses Windows and you have some compiled modules (i.e. node-sass or bcrypt), sharing those makes either the container or the host not able to use them.

Another solution that comes up frequently is to separate the node_modules installation step in your Dockerfile, and to override the volume mount for this. You will still need to rebuild the Docker image every time you want to add a package, but this (probably) shouldn't happen that often down the road.

Here's the relevant parts of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.8.1-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package*.json .
COPY ./yarn.lock .

RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Then, in your docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: 'app_DEV'
    build: .
    command: sh -c "yarn install && node ./server.js"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    tty: true
```

Make sure you include the `/usr/src/app/node_modules/` volume **AFTER** the root mount, as it will override it within the container. Also, the trailing slash in important.

Comment: I also woldn't recommend to share `node_modules`. In case of pnpm and e.g. windows host and linux container the content of `node_modules` is not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

In your case in order to have it working in the way you want, you should add the `USER` in the docker file and the `user:` in the docker-compose.yml. e.g.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.8.1-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

USER node

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: 'app_DEV'
    build: .
    command: sh -c "yarn install && node ./server.js"
    user: "1000:1000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    tty: true
```

Anyway, we faced a similar situation and we opted for a different approach. Instead of sharing the node_modules folder between host and container (nasty behaviors if you work with colleagues using different OS) we decided to avoid mounting the node_modules folder in the docker-compose.yml.

In our case the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:8.12.0-stretch

RUN mkdir /api

WORKDIR /api

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --prod

COPY . .

CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js" ]
```

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./:/api"
      - "/api/node_modules/"
```

This way we're able to create the node_modules in the host (that can be used for testing, development and so on) and safely keep unchanged the content of the docker container. The downside of this approach is that our devs have to run the `npm ci` also on the host and they need to recreate the image every time the package.json is changed.

Comment: (Putting `node_modules` in a volume actively prevents Docker from installing any new or changed modules, even if the `package.json` file changes.)